# Which math supports increasing Bitcoin blocksize requiring a gigabit connection?

Tags: block-size-increase

According to Bitcoin Core developer Gregory Maxwell:

“There’s an inherent tradeoff between scale and decentralization when you talk about transactions on the network. […] You’d need a lot of bandwidth, on the order of a gigabit connection. It would work. The problem is that it wouldn’t be very decentralized, because who is going to run a node?”

https://cointelegraph.com/explained/block-size-and-scalability-explained

Which math supports increasing the blocksize to 4 MB or even 32 MB, requiring a gigabit connection?